# How can I limit variable size in to maximium of 32 KB in Oracle Forms?

Tags: variables, size, oracleforms

I am working with Oracle Forms 6i and I want to limit the size of the return value of a functions in to 32KB. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling a function that returns a VARCHAR2, it's already limited to 32,767 bytes.

(If you want to limit it to something less than that, you'd add some validation code to the function to check the return value length, and raise an exception if the validation fails).